# parallel filesystem without SAN infrastructure

Tags: filesystems, storage, storage-area-network

Is there any parallel filesystem that doesn't need SAN infrastructure ? What I want to do is to create a logical volume and attach it with multiple VMs that will use the disk concurrently.I don't want to use NFS. because I want block level access.

Comment: What about using SAN to one system and then using NFS to the others.  You forgot to mention the Operating System, distribution, and version in your question.

Comment: well I'll use linux preferably fedora or debian not so strict about version

Comment: Ceph and GlusterFS come to mind.

Comment: can GlusterFS or Ceph work without IP ?

Comment: In some of your comments you mention "without IP".  But you don't mention any such restriction in your question.  You would probably get much better answers if you more fully explained what it is you need to do, and why you have these restrictions.  Explaining why helps us to fully understand the restrictions, someone might have a better way of achieving your end goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mount a remote filesystem, you use an NFS share. A SAN, in the context you're using the word, provides disk-level access to multiple servers. This requires the servers to be members of a cluster, usually, and is not used for basic file sharing.

Comment: I don't want to use NFS. its better to provide an object store like S3 than NFS. I want concurrent block level access without IP

Comment: Block means SCSI, not object.

Answer (score 0):

With VMware, you can attach the same virtual disk to multiple VMs running on the same host.

However, you'll still need the VMs to be aware of this and run some kind of clustering software, otherwise filesystem corruption will ensure instantly.

Which, BTW, is exactly the same thing that will occur if you connect the same SAN volume to two or more non-cluster-aware VMs. There's just no way to share a filesystem if the computers accessing it are not cooperating.